# prove the sign of $1+2x-e^x$ around 0

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to prove that the sign of $1+2x-e^x$  around $0$ is negative if $x\to 0^-$ and positive if $x\to 0^+$. If I replace $e^x$ by its equivalent function (the tangent at 0) I conclude that the sign of this expression depends on the sign of $x$ as I have $1+2x - 1-x $.
I need this step to compute the limit of $\frac{1+2x+e^x}{1+2x-e^x}$ when $x\to 0$

Comment: What about the Taylor series of $e^x$ ?

Comment: Hint: you should be able to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1+2x-e^x}x$ as a nonzero constant; since $1+2x-e^x = \frac{1+2x-e^x}x \cdot x$, that will tell you the sign of $1+2x-e^x$ on each side of $0$.

Comment: If you can use derivatives, then you know $f(x)=1+2x−e^x$ is increasing at $0$. Combine this fact with $f(0)=0$.

Comment: The derivative of $1+2x-e^x$ at $x=0$ tells you what happens either side of the $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You should already know from the definition that:
$$
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^k}{k!}+...
$$
Obviously for all $x>0$:   $e^x>1+x$. To consider negative $x$'s we write:
$$
e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}(1-\frac x4)+...+\frac{x^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}(1-\frac x{2m+2})+...
$$
Thus for small negative $x$, all the terms starting on the $\frac{x^3}{3!}(1-\frac x4) $ term are negative and we conclude:
$$
e^x<1+x+\frac{x^2}2
$$
for small negative $x$.
From the above we get that $1+2x-e^x>1+2x-(1+x)=x>0$ for small positive $x$ and  $1+2x-e^x<1+2x-(1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2})=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}<0 $ for small negative $x$.